# C# Parsing hidden fields with the HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack, hidden-fields

I need to write an application for a friends site which parses hidden fields. I've downloaded the Html Agility Pack library, but I'm kinda confused because there are not really any examples. The HTML field looks like this:

```
<input type = "hidden" autocomplete="off" value="randomvalue" name="foo">
```

How would I go about getting the value from this field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from memory, something like:

```
var value = docroot.SelectSingleNode("//input[@type='hidden' and @name='foo']")
                .Attributes["value"].Value;
```